# Java align list item markers in JEditorPane

Tags: java, jeditorpane

I want to align list item markers to right or center. However because of `list-style-position` not working i couldn't do it. Here is sample of code:

```
JEditorPane pane1 = new JEditorPane();
pane1.setContentType("text/html");
pane1.setEditable(false);
String data="<ol style=\"list-style-position: inside; text-align: right;\">" +
    "<li>List Item 1</li>"+
    "<li>List Item 2</li>"+
    "</ol>";
pane1.setText(data);
```

This is not resulting as in the browser. Is there any way to achieve aligning list item markers with the content in java ?

**EDIT:**
In javax.swing.text.html.CSS -[here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/javax/swing/text/html/CSS.java#CSS.Attribute.0LIST_STYLE_POSITION)- I can found that list-style-position is supported.